# Getting a NgForm instance from an Angular directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a behavior where all my forms that are attached to a `preventFormChangesLoss` directive will behave so that if there are changes to the form (if it's not `pristine` or `submitted`), the page shows a warning when the user wants to leave.

For that, I am trying to get my directive to get the NgForm instance my directive is attached to.
For now, I have

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[preventFormChangesLoss]'
})
export class PreventFormChangesLoss implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  private origin: string = '';

  @ViewChild('myForm') form : NgForm;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.elRef);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.elRef, this.form);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.elRef, this.form); // shows the native element, + 'undefined'
  }
}
```

And I use it with

```
<form preventFormChangesLoss #myForm="ngForm">
...
</form>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, and I also would like my directive to get the NgForm instance without having to do the `#myForm="ngForm"` part, so that I can name my forms however I want and keep this behavior separate.

How can I do that, and can someone point me to the right place in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot grab the form element like that because it's not part of directive's *view*. Instead you should directly **inject** it.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[preventFormChangesLoss]'
})
export class PreventFormChangesLoss implements OnInit {
  private origin: string = '';

  constructor(private ngForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.ngForm);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.ngForm)
  }
}
```

This will allow you to manipulate and subscribe to events of the specific Angular-enhanced `<form>` from within the directive, so you'll only be using it like so:

```
<form preventFormChangesLoss>
...
</form>
```

---

Not as per your design, but a tip: Since you said that you want to do this for *all* your forms, it might be simpler to change your selector to `form:not([allowFormChangesLoss])`. Then you just need to import the module to your shared module, and *all* your already created forms will have this functionality. In case you want to disable it on a specific form, you can use `<form allowFormChangesLoss>`, thus inversing the "default" behavior.

Comment: If you just inject the NgForm to a directive, it automatically creates ControlContainer as NgForm does?

Comment: This example doesn't work with Angular 8. It gives an StaticInjector/NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm!. And yes, I have imported ReactiveFormsModule in the app.module.ts . Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `constructor(@Self() private formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective) {}`